# How to animate blocks one after the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate.css

With this bit of JavaScript I hoped to animate some block element one after the other by adding CSS animation classes with a time out of 500 milliseconds.

Unfortunately it waits one time and all the boxes slide up at once after the one wait.

Here is the script so far:

```
var blocks = $('.block');

blocks.each(function(index, obj) {
    var block = $(obj);
    setTimeout(function() {
        block.addClass('animated slideInUp');
    }, 500);
});
```

So, how do I add these classes asynchronically so the boxes on the page will slide up one after the other?

Comment: You can divide the time by number of blocks. And then, inside of setTimeout, increase the time with every iteration from 0 to 500.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the `index` of the `each()` loop so that in `setTimeout()`  the time will be multiple of `500`. With this the boxes will appear in each `500` milliseconds as the `setTimeout()` will have timeout time as `500`, `1000`, `1500`, ... and so on.

```
var blocks = $('.block');
blocks.each(function(index, obj) {
    var block = $(obj);
    setTimeout(function() {
        block.addClass('animated slideInUp');
    }, 500*index);
});
```

Comment: You could use `index`, which is already there, to have the same effect.

Comment: Elegant solution, thanks. I was expecting promises, lasers and explosions. But this works fine I guess.

Comment: @Floris glad to help :)